# Can Saudi Arabia immigration search electronic devices?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, electronic-items, saudi-arabia

In Saudi Arabia, there are a lot of things that are commonplace in Europe and illegal there.

Are immigration authorities known to inspect the files on computers and phones for things that would be considered against the morals? For example :

- Intimate pictures that a couple may share with each other
- Dating apps, especially those where people can exchange pictures through the messaging function

Would it be good advice to delete the pictures and uninstall those apps beforehand to someone who would need to travel into the country for business? Doing it would keep things on the safe side but risk a loss of contacts & messages history, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

They probably have the rights to search your devices; customs officers tend to have a more leeway when comes the time to search incoming travellers. (this apply not only to Saudi Arabia)

You could probably refuse and you will probably be refused entry and send back.

Make a backup of your devices before leaving and sanitize your devices, remove anything that could be considered too "spicy"; photos, videos, dating apps (especially gay apps) ...

Answer (score 1):

Checking the contents of your devices is not allowed by the Saudi law, except if there is a warrant. This applies to all law enforcement departments.

I have been travelling in and out of Saudi for many years (as a Saudi myself), this has never happened.